# Using `xcookybooky` with lettrine v2.01

Tags: lettrine, xcookybooky

Since the update of the `lettrine` package to version 2.01 the following MWE no longer compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcookybooky}

\begin{document}

\begin{recipe}{Back}  
  \preparation{%
        \step test
  }
\end{recipe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Corresponding bug report: https://github.com/SvenHarder/xcookybooky/issues/13

Comment: Problem was fixed in https://github.com/SvenHarder/xcookybooky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be fixed with this redefinition of `\step`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcookybooky}

\renewcommand{\step}
{%
    \stepcounter{step}%
    \lettrine
    [%
        lines=2,
        lhang=0,          % space into margin, value between 0 and 1
        loversize=0.15,   % enlarges the height of the capital
        slope=0em,
        findent=1em,      % gap between capital and intended text
        nindent=0em       % shifts all intended lines, begining with the second line
    ]{\thestep}{}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{recipe}{Back}  
  \preparation{%
    \step test
  }
\end{recipe}

\end{document}
```

---

This problem was fixed in the github version of the `xcookybooky` package available from https://github.com/SvenHarder/xcookybooky

Comment: A `%` was missing; on the other hand, the package has so many missing ones that this might appear useless.

Comment: It produces `Package tabulary Warning: No suitable columns! on input line 30`
 and   `Package wrapfig Warning: wraptable used inside a conflicting environment on input line 30.`

Comment: @SimonDispa To keep the example short, I did not include the ingredients. Once you add them, tabulary should be happy

Comment: Still remains the `Package wrapfig Warning:`

Comment: @SimonDispa Yes, that normal for `xcookybooky`. You would need to basically reimplement the package.