# Expand xcookybooky recipe to larger width

Tags: paper-size, xcookybooky

Very new to tex, and trying to use xcookybooky to layout a few recipes for printing. I'd like to print on square pages, specifically 11in by 11in, but when I set paperwidth and paperheight for the geometry package like:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=11in,paperheight=11in]{geometry}
```

I just seem to have extra whitespace on the right when running `pdflatex`.

I can't seem to find any option in xcookybooky documentation, is there a more "global" tex option I should be setting to get the contents to fill the pagewidth?

EDIT: Adding MWE, mostly taken from the xcookybooky example https://github.com/SvenHarder/xcookybooky/tree/master/example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=11in,paperheight=11in]{geometry}

% encoding, font, language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}


\usepackage{nicefrac}

\usepackage[
    nowarnings,
    %myconfig
]
{xcookybooky}

\begin{document}
% Complete recipe example


\begin{recipe}
[% 
    preparationtime = {\unit[1]{h}},
    portion = {\portion{6}},
]
{Rice and Lamb}



    \introduction{%
      Introduction to the dish
    }

    \ingredients{%
        \unit[2]{tbsp} & Vegetable Oil\\
        3 & Onion, chopped\\
        2 pound & Stewing Lamb or Beef\\
        \unit[1]{tbsp} & Minced Garlic\\
        \unit[2]{tsp} & Salt\\
        \unit[8]{cups} & Water\\
        \unit[1.5]{tbsp} & Ground Cardamom\\
    }

    \preparation{%
      \step Do some things
      \step Do some other things
      \step Finish doing things
    }

\end{recipe}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think you need `marginparsep=0pt,
marginparwidth=0pt,` but please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thanks CarLaTex, added MWE above. Tried to add marginparsesep and marginparwidth but didn't see any changes. Thanks!

Comment: @Peck some of the problems can be repaired with `\usepackage{xcookybooky}
\setlength{\textwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}`, but the real problem is that `xcookbooky` has a *lot* of hard coded stuff...

Comment: ah, thanks @samcarter, I'm open to using anything else, this is just helping a friend out with a charity cookbook project and learning some tex (in a way beyond just pushing to it from Pandoc). I'd be open to using other packages if there are more flexible options that give something similar as far as layout.

Comment: @Peck You can find some related package suggestions at https://ctan.org/recommendations/xcookybooky Personally I find `xccokybooky` the best looking, but doing non-standard stuff is not easy and it is no longer compatible with up-to-date latex distributions.

Comment: To amend my previous comment: the incompatibilities with current tex distributions have been fixed in the development version available from https://github.com/SvenHarder/xcookybooky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy `xcookybooky.sty` in the working directory and edit it so that the lines

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{24.0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt} %0cm
\setlength{\headsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.4cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}
```

become

```
\@ifpackageloaded{geometry}{}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{15.5cm}%
  \setlength{\textheight}{24.0cm}%
  \setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm}%
  \setlength{\headheight}{14pt}%0cm
  \setlength{\headsep}{1cm}%
  \setlength{\topskip}{0cm}%
  \setlength{\footskip}{1.4cm}%
  \setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5cm}%
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}%
  \setlength{\voffset}{0cm}%
  \setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}%
}
```

Thus, if `geometry` is loaded before `xcookybooky`, the package will set page parameters not according to its own ideas, but the user's.

You also need a fix to avoid a spurious error when using `xcookybooky` with TeX Live 2018 (that has an updated version of `lettrine`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=11in,paperheight=11in,margin=1in]{geometry}

% encoding, font, language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}


\usepackage{nicefrac}

\usepackage[
    nowarnings,
    %myconfig
]
{xcookybooky}

% fix from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445886/
\renewcommand{\step}
{%
    \stepcounter{step}%
    \lettrine
    [%
        lines=2,
        lhang=0,          % space into margin, value between 0 and 1
        loversize=0.15,   % enlarges the height of the capital
        slope=0em,
        findent=1em,      % gap between capital and intended text
        nindent=0em       % shifts all intended lines, begining with the second line
    ]{\thestep}{}%
}

\begin{document}
% Complete recipe example


\begin{recipe}
[% 
    preparationtime = {\unit[1]{h}},
    portion = {\portion{6}},
]
{Rice and Lamb}



    \introduction{%
      Introduction to the dish
    }

    \ingredients{%
        \unit[2]{tbsp} & Vegetable Oil\\
        3 & Onion, chopped\\
        2 pound & Stewing Lamb or Beef\\
        \unit[1]{tbsp} & Minced Garlic\\
        \unit[2]{tsp} & Salt\\
        \unit[8]{cups} & Water\\
        \unit[1.5]{tbsp} & Ground Cardamom\\
    }

    \preparation{%
      \step Do some things
      \step Do some other things
      \step Finish doing things
    }

\end{recipe}

\end{document}
```

[image]