# Entries moved out of order when trying multiple preparations in xcookybooky

Tags: miktex, xcookybooky

## Issue

I am writing several recipe entries to a cookbook I am putting together. For this purpose I am using the package `xcookybooky`. For some recipes I would like to be able to split up the preparation steps into groupings (e.g., "the roast", "the sauce", etc.). I have tried applying code from entries here (see below) but to no avail. Essentially what I am seeing is that the preparation steps are wrapped around to the start of the recipe, throwing off the entire recipe page (see below).

## What I have read

My main approach has been based on this response: [Multiple preparations in xcookybooky](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/689126/300422).

## MWE

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper,
11pt
]{article}

\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[]{xcookybooky}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{preparationnumber}\setcounter{preparationnumber}{1}
\setHeadlines{prephead = Preparation method~\thepreparationnumber}% define the heading <<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand*{\prepreparation}[1]
{% Hook: entered before the preparation (steps)
    \def\xcb@hook@prepreparation
    {%
        \xcb@name@prephead% 
        \xcb@fontsize@prep\color{\xcb@color@prep} #1%
         \vspace*{2em}\stepcounter{preparationnumber}\setcounter{step}{0}
    }  
}
\renewcommand*{\postpreparation}[1]
{% Hook: entered after the preparation (steps)
    \def\xcb@hook@postpreparation
    {\vspace*{2em}\setcounter{step}{0}\stepcounter{preparationnumber}% 
        \xcb@name@prephead% 
        \xcb@fontsize@prep\color{\xcb@color@prep} #1%           
    }
}

\makeatother    

% fix from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445886/
\renewcommand{\step}
{%
    \stepcounter{step}%
    \lettrine
    [%
    lines=2,
    lhang=0,          % space into margin, value between 0 and 1
    loversize=0.15,   % enlarges the height of the capital
    slope=0em,
    findent=1em,      % gap between capital and intended text
    nindent=0em       % shifts all intended lines, begining with the second line
    ]{\thestep}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{recipe}
[%
preparationtime={\unit[45]{m}},
portion={\portion{4-6}},
]
{Recipe Title}

\ingredients[35]{
\textbf{List - 1} \\
\unit[2]{T} & & olive oil \\ 
\unit[1]{} & & red onion \\
\unit[6]{cloves} & & garlic \\
\textbf{List - 2} \\
\unit[1]{} & &  cucumber\\ 
\unit[1]{cup} & \unit[245]{g} & yogurt \\ 
\unit[2]{cloves} & & garlic \\
\textbf{List - 3} \\
\multicolumn{3}{r}{pita wraps} \\
\multicolumn{3}{r}{shredded red cabbage} \\
}

\prepreparation{Main}{
\step \lipsum[1][1-4]
\step \lipsum[2][1-4]
\step \lipsum[3][1-4]
}
\preparation{Sauce}{
\step \lipsum[1][1-4]
\step \lipsum[2][1-4]
}

\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

## Results

[image]

As can be seen in the image, the recipe title and ingredients now appear below the preparation steps, which have somehow been added to the top of the recipe. Any help getting this correctly formatted would be greatly appreciated!